# Does angular2 bootstrap have a way to dynamically target elements like it does in angular 1.x

Tags: angular

Assuming we were to add some DOM elements at runtime:

```js
var element = document.createElement('app');
element.id = 'app1';
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(element);

var element2 = document.createElement('app');
element2.id = 'app2';
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(element2);
```

Angular 1.x `bootstrap` method can target a specific DOM element, so you can  bootstrap Angular on them:

```js
angular.bootstrap(element, ['myApp']);
angular.bootstrap(element2, ['myApp']);
```

In Angular2 the `bootstrap` method takes in a `Component` instead of an element and uses the component's `selector` to locate an element to bootstrap, which (as of build **2.0.0-alpha.26**) only bootstraps the first match it finds:

```js
import { Component, bootstrap } from 'angular2/angular2';

@Component({ selector: 'app' })
export class MyApp { }
bootstrap(MyApp);
```

So that being said, does anyone know if there is a way (or going to be a way) to bootstrap similar to 1.x, allowing you to dynamically apply angular to elements on the fly?

Answer (score 2):

part of this question - related to the bootstrapping is answered here [How use an AngularJS 2 component multiple times in the same page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30807935/angular-2-how-use-component-multiple-times-in-the-same-page) the rest of the answer depends on how you want to create the elements.

For example, one way to add components dynamically is to do it from the data associated with an application. If the data changes (e.g. an Array), then the component would be inserted into the DOM using `NgFor`

```
<template *ng-for="#item of #items">
    <my-component>{{item.name}}</my-component>
</template>
```

Here is the comment in the Angular 2 code

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/directives/ng_for.ts#L7

Comment: Both of these rely on a single bootstrap call though, right? So still a single "angular" app rather than an architecture of multiple "angular" apps. What I'm hoping for is the ability to have multiple apps without needing to have unique components for each app, so each "app" could get injectables and such unique to it.

But maybe the answer to doing that lies within an architecture of injecting services into the single component that have some sort of "app" context that they control so each component instance can be unique.

Comment: I believe that is not a design goal of Angular and you would have to do the bootstrapping yourself