# How to use an AngularJS 2 component multiple times in the same page?

Tags: javascript, angular

After declaring a component with selector `'some-comp'`, using `<some-comp></some-comp>` in a page will only work once. I would like to use it multiple times any help, here is an example code:

```
@Component({ selector: 'some-comp' })
@View({ template: 'component template' })
class SomeComponent {    }
bootstrap(SomeComponent);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bootstrapped Component is really to be looked at as an app, if you want to use the same component multiple times, you will want to make it into a directive and then include that directive in your app which you bootstrap.

Look at this menu component as an example, you will see the `<aria-menuitem>` components used multiple times as well as the `<aria-menu>` components.

https://github.com/dylanb/Axponents/tree/master/angular2

Comment: I agree, but since I'm using angular 2 in an already written application I'll have to do a lot of refactoring to achieve that. Thanks for the answer.